# Post a new note specifying privacy

Tags: facebook-graph-api, privacy

I'm trying to post a note using Facebook Graph API.
I would like to restrict the note visibility to myself only.
Therefore I am passing the following param: privacy={'value':'SELF'}

Unfortunately it is still created with the EVERYONE privacy.

Do you know if there is a way to specify privacy when creating a note?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the documentation, "privacy" doesn't exist as a field for notes, so I don't believe it's possible.  Here's the reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/